# Timing Manager and Worker Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronize

I am having trouble getting the synchronization of my managers and workers to go through correctly. The problem is that the SyncManager is stopping before the SyncWorker is done... And I don't know why it is continuing to execute without waiting for the SyncWorker to finish.

### SyncManager

```c#
public void ExecuteTask()
{
    /*Code to set up Variables*/
    while (fileMetadata.Count > 0 && Status != WorkerStatus.ShouldStop)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastUpdate).Minutes > 1)
            _serviceLog.WriteEntry(ProgressString());

        if (Status == WorkerStatus.ShouldStop)
            break;

        SyncFile(fileMetadata[0]);

        //Possible solution
        //Wait for Sync File to Finish before stepping (although logically it should do that)

        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastUpdate).Minutes > 1)
            _serviceLog.WriteEntry(ProgressString());

        //Code That I think is causing the error
        fileMetadata.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    /*Code to preform clean up actions and notify user of all transfers*/
}

public void SyncFile(FileMetadata fmd)
    {
        lock (executionLock)
        {
            attempts++;
            long waitTime = 0;
            switch (Type)
            {
                case (SyncManagerType.UploadLarge):
                    waitTime = 8192;
                    break;
                case (SyncManagerType.UploadMedium):
                    waitTime = 4096;
                    break;
                case (SyncManagerType.DownloadLarge):
                    waitTime = 8192;
                    break;
                case (SyncManagerType.DownloadMedium):
                    waitTime = 4096;
                    break;
                default:
                    waitTime = 30;
                    break;
            }

            syncWorker = new FileSyncWorker(GenerateSyncWorkerID(), _serviceLog, fmd, ref sb);
            syncThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(syncWorker.ExecuteTask));
            syncThread.Start();
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime finish;

            while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds < waitTime && (syncWorker.Status == WorkerStatus.Working))
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastUpdate).Minutes > 1)
                    _serviceLog.WriteEntry(ProgressString());

                if (Status == WorkerStatus.ShouldStop)
                    waitTime = 15;

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            finish = DateTime.Now;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (finish.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds < waitTime)
            {
                if (syncWorker.Status == WorkerStatus.CompletedSuccess)
                {
                    successes++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                syncThread.Abort();
                sb.AppendLine("Sync Manager (" + ID + ") - FSW (" + syncWorker.ID + ") - Transfer timed out after " + waitTime + " seconds.");
            }

            //Possible Solution
            //FileMetadata toRemove = fileMetadata.Find(delegate(FileMetadata f) { return f.Equals(syncWorker.FileData); });
            //fileMetadata.Remove(toRemove);

            activeIDs.RemoveAll(delegate(int i) { return i == syncWorker.ID; });
            syncWorker = null;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the parent thread to wait for the worker make sure you put a `Thread.Join` before exiting:

```
if (finish.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds < waitTime)
{
     if (syncWorker.Status == WorkerStatus.CompletedSuccess)
     {
          successes++;
     }
}
else
{
     syncThread.Abort();
     syncThread.Join();
     sb.AppendLine("Sync Manager (" + ID + ") - FSW (" + syncWorker.ID + ") - Transfer timed out after " + waitTime + " seconds.");
}
```

Comment: Well, the issue is that if there is only one file to sync, then the manager will close out before the thread is done executing rather than waiting for the thread to finish. This seems to happen randomly with out regard to if the worker completed successfully or not.

Comment: @Blaze Phoenix: But adding the join should force the manager to wait for the worker thread.

Comment: @BlazePhoenix what he mean that this is base `Join()` method - it will wait forever for thread. There's other overloaded version of `Thread.Join()` that will wait for specific ammount of time and continue anyway - whenever the thread is finished it's work or not

Comment: Thanks I was able to use this to develop the solution, the other issue was I was locking the whole method call, so certain other events would not occur.